# Posts Page in React js

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, jsx

I have posts page every post have id . how i can  listen to scroll and save the current post_id   that user can start where he left off ?

I wont to make thing like this : onUserSeePost : post postId to back_end

Answer (score 0):

Your question is not clear, Kindly add some code.

Add a scroll event listener. Store the scroll location in the localstorage, When the
user returns to the page scroll him back to the location

```
//Event listener to store the scroll position
addEventListener("scroll", function (e) {
  // Get the new Value
  var newValue = e.target.scrollTop;
  //Subtract the two and conclude
  if (oldValue - newValue < 0) {
    console.log("down");
  } else if (oldValue - newValue > 0) {
    console.log("up");
  }
  // Update the old value
  oldValue = newValue;
});

//scroll him back
function scrollMe() {
  el.scrollTop = localStorage.getItem("myscroll");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if I get the idea, for what you want to do, but if you want to be in the exact same position where the user left the `scroll bar` you could use the property of the window `window.scrollY`, you can see an example [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/scroll_event), but I think you don't need a event handler, maybe you could use the `localStorage` API to do the trick, save that position then just check if there is some position saved in the `localStorage` and just do something like:

`window.scrollY = 700` <= value in pixels, from where is going to be the scroll bar in the Y axis on the document.